# PHP change keys in array

Tags: php, arrays, key

hello i have an array like this and i want to change the area key to info1 like `$values ["Area"]` will become `$values ["info1"]`,`$values ["Shop"]` should be `$values ["info2"]` and so on but evertime I run my code it throws errormessages like "undefined index" but I really dont know why.

```php
$values ["standort"] = "60071-00001";
$values ["desc"] = "car";
$values ["street"] = "first ave";
$values ["number"] = "98";
$values ["postcode"] = "40764";
$values ["city"] = "London";
$values ["Area"] = "15";
$values ["Shop"] = "430";
$values ["SalesArea"] = "1998";
$values ["info4"] = "";
$values ["info5"] = "";

// echo var_dump(array_keys($values));

for($i=6;$i<=10;$i++){
    $j= array_keys($values)[$i];
    if($i==6){
        $values["info1"]=$values[$j];
        unset($values[$j]);

    }
    if($i==7){
        $values["info2"]=$values[$j];
        unset($values[$j]);

    }
    if($i==8){
        $values["info3"]=$values[$j];
        unset($values[$j]);

    }
    if($i==9){
        $values["info4"]=$values[$j];
        unset($values[$j]);

    }
    if($i==10){
        $values["info5"]=$values[$j];
        unset($values[$j]);

    }

}
```

Comment: Plz show the exact error message(s).

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\php\index.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\php\index.php on line 39

Answer (score 1):

There is no true way to "replace" a key in an array in PHP, but you can add a new one and then remove the old one like so:

```
$values['info1'] = $values['Area'];
unset($values['Area']);
```

Comment: but my problem is the key values or area or shop are user generated so i dont know them before

Comment: Show me some code to better explain the problem.  You should be able to set it regardless.

Comment: $values ["Area"] = "15";
$values ["Shop"] = "430";
$values ["SalesArea"] = "1998";
$values ["info4"] = ""; 
$values ["info5"] = "";

Comment: all there keys area ,shop and salesarea are from the user

Comment: I'm not understanding what prevents you from doing the above.

Comment: and all i want is to replace the user keys with my keys so transform area into info1 or salesarea into info3

Comment: im still getting error messages iand i dont know why like 
 
Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\php\index.php on line 17 Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\php\index.php on line 39

Comment: In your array you're referencing the index/key of 10 but it doesn't exist.  Make it exist or don't reference it.